# How I can Get Records of Specific date in Microsoft Access Database like 10/21/2018 dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: database, ms-access

Here is Code of My Query Search in MS-ACCESS (.MDB),
I am trying this

```
Select * from Records where date like '10/21/2018%'
```

Comment: Which data type is the field?  Also in my opinion it's best to avoid field names that are also the names of functions or reserved words (like `date`)

Comment: **Date/Time** @ashleedawg

Comment: So you want to return the records between `2018-10-21 00:00:00` and `2018-10-22 00:00:00`, correct?  (as in midnight to midnight?)   if so, this comment is a pretty big hint as to the answer...  ‎

Comment: @ashleedawg Can I get Record With Exact Date? like exactly 10/21/2018?

Comment: Yes @ashleedawg I Got Your Hint I have Where Clause with User ID and Eatct date     `Select * records from table where userid = 1 and date like 10/21/2018` ?

Comment: "exactly" 10/21/2018 means 10/21/2018 at midnight ('2018-10-21 00:00:00`) ... if there are times attached to this datetime field and you want results for more than a single second of the day, then you should specify a range using `Between`.   This would be much easier to answer if your question were to include a sample of your data, and an example of what that data would look like after your query returns it...

Comment: Sorry my hint implied: `SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourDateField BETWEEN '2018-10-21 00:00:00' AND '2018-10-22 00:00:00'` ... (I hope your table isn't actually called `TABLE` and that your Date field isn't actually called `DATE`.)

Comment: This is an extremely basic question, unless you think there is something in your question that I am not understanding, in which case please post a sample of your data, and an example of what your query should return.  Also please see **How to create an [mcve]** as well as "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site.

Comment: See; **[Examples of using dates as criteria in Access queries](https://support.office.com/article/examples-of-using-dates-as-criteria-in-access-queries-aea83b3b-46eb-43dd-8689-5fc961f21762)**

Answer (score 3):

It will be:

```
select * from Records where [date] = #10/21/2018#
```

Addendum:

One method to ignore a *time part* of the date field:

```
select * from Records where Fix([date]) = #10/21/2018#
```

Comment: I like your answer, but unable to get records using this query

Comment: @ArslanAli  If this query does not work for you, it indicates that either 1) your date/time values actually have time values included that are not `00:00:00` so that they are not exactly equal to `#10/21/2018 00:00:00#`, OR 2) your data actually does not have any values with `#10/21/2018#` and the only reason the other variations return values is because the dates are within the faulty range that you specified in your answer.  Of course only you can know your data, but from details you shared in your question and comments, it seems that the data may not contain values which you think they do.

Comment: My answer is the answer to your question: _Can I get Record With Exact Date? like exactly 10/21/2018?_. So - if you get no records - no record has this exact date. If a time part is involved, see the addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following Query Solve my issue, Thanks @ashleedawg and @Gustav for your suggestions.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE > #10/20/2018# AND DATE < #10/22/2018#
```

Comment: DATE >= #10/20/2018#

Comment: This is not valid for all cases, especially if dates might have time values.  `#10/20/2018#` essentially means `#10/20/2018 00:00:00#`, so the value `#10/20/2018 01:00:00#` would fall within the range specified, but it would not be the desired range.  Also, because Date is a reserved function name, you are likely to get errors.  Use brackets to ensure it is interpreted as a column name: `[DATE] >= #10/21/2018# AND [DATE] < #10/22/2018#`.  Finally, **if the date values will only have date values (and no time values), then just compare it directly like `[DATE] = #10/21/2018#`**.

Comment: I now see that @ashleedawg already explained in comments the same thing that I just commented.  The fact that your query works and that you ignored ashleedawg's suggestions indicates that they query is not working for the reasons you think it is working.  Your query is **not** testing for *exactly* 10/21/2018.

Answer (score 0):

If your `date` column is of datatype datetime, using the `like` operator will convert your datetime to text which depends on regional settings. Also, the placeholder for "any string" in Access is `*`, not `%`. Assuming that you used that placeholder to ignore the time, you better try something like this:

```
Select * from Records where DateValue([date]) = #10/21/2018#
```